# Do polyfluorosulfuric acids like H2SO2F4 exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I was thinking about a compound resembling $\ce{H2SO4}$ but more acidic. I thought to replace the 2 oxygens with 4 fluorine atoms getting $\ce{H2SO2F4}$, which might be more acidic. Does such a compound even exist?

I also tried searching another compound i.e. $\ce{HOSF5}$ thinking of it to be more acidic than the previous but no results.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorosulfuric_acid.

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments imply, no dice.  You can, of course, make a six-coordinate sulfur compound with the formula $\ce{SF6}$.  But trying it with a mixture of oxide, hydroxide and fluoride ligands instead of just fluoride presents the opportunity to evolve $\ce{HF}$ leaving the sulfur with a lower coordination number.  There is a five-coordinate compound [$\ce{SOF4}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thionyl_tetrafluoride), but otherwise you should expect the sulfur to get down to four-coordination.  So the only stable protic acids you can get with one sulfur atom and oxide, hydroxide and fluoride ligands are plain old $\ce{H2SO4}$ and the more strongly acidic [$\ce{HSO3F}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorosulfuric_acid).

Comment: It's a different thing with heaver chalcogens. [Teflic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflic_acid) is fine with hexa-coordinated Te.