# Acid HClF6 and HIF6

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I was wondering about $\ce{HClO4}$ which is a very strong acid . I thought it can be made stronger by replacing $\ce O$ with $\ce F$ to make $\ce{HClF6}$ but didn't find its existence . I thought that it might be unstable due to repulsions between $\ce F$ . So than i switched to $\ce{HIF6}$ and there was no existence of this also as well as $\ce{HBrF6}$ . Is there a reason that the halogens cannot form $\ce{HXF6}$ acids similar to $\ce{HSbF6}$?

Comment: Related (involving sfur as the centrasl atom):  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102290/do-polyfluorosulfuric-acids-like-h2so2f4-exist/102294#102294.  You tend to lose hydrogen halide molecules from your proposed complexes.

Comment: ClF6- , BrF6- and IF6- all exist, as does IF8- . However I doubt the parent acids will be stable, but my good chemistry books are a long way away at the moment.

Comment: There are a [whole bunch of these ions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhalogen_ions).  But the reference does not document any case where anions can be protonated to acids.

Comment: Why can't they protonated to acids.  is there any known reason

Comment: Can't they be protnated by superacids

Comment: Nothing wrong with protonation as such.  The issue could be they decompose when protonated; compare with a nitrite or a bicarbonate..